# provider for @MethodSource not found

Tags: java, maven, junit

I don't understand why the method referenced by @MethodSource is not found. Below is my application test class:

```
import domain.Game;
import domain.Player;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class GameRepositoryPostgresSpec{

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("newGameProvider")
    void create(Game newGame) {

    }

    static Stream<Game> newGameProvider(){
        return Stream.of(
                new Game(new Player(), "", 0, false)
        );
    }
    
}
```

which gives

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateExtensionContext does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExecutableInvoker getExecutableInvoker()' of interface org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.

    at org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodArgumentsProvider.lambda$provideArguments$1(MethodArgumentsProvider.java:55)
...
    Suppressed: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
```

This is the pom of my application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.packt.tdd.ch4</groupId>
    <artifactId>wordz</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm following the documentation: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for your paremeterized tests looks ok so far...but what I'm missing is the definition of your used plugins or more accurately the versions.. like this:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.12.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Just as a simple example try the following:

```
  record Person (String name, int age) {
  }

  static Stream<Person> name() {
    return Stream.of(
        new Person("first", 23),
        new Person("second", 65)
    );
  }

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource
  void name(Person person) {
    System.out.println("person = " + person);
  }
```

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.1</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  ..

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
```

You can also check this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-2 and the YT video.

Comment: I'm not sure why I would want specific version for the maven plugins... anyway I fixed by importing the junit-bom version 5.10.1 (as you show) which specifies version 5.10.1 for junit-jupiter-param. So I guess the problem came from my junit-jupiter-param 5.9.2 version and... java 17 maybe?

Comment: `I'm not sure why I would want specific version for the maven plugins..` that makes sure your build is reproducible... otherwise other versions of plugins could be used for example if new versions will be releases and might possible break your build..

Comment: Best practices is to always define all plugin versions in your build...